# Can key be dynamic according user selction in the dataverse table?

Tags: database, dataverse, power-platform

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve dynamic key constraints based on user selections in Power Platform Dataverse.

For example, I have a `Student` table with four columns:

| ID | Student | Course | Lecturer | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | Math | Andrew | Math_1 |
| 2 | Sam | English | Andrew | English_1 |
| 3 | Lily | Math | Jack | Math_1 |
| 4 | Lily | Math | Jack | Math_2 |
| 5 | Dona | Math | Ben | Math_1 |

Normally, I want the `[Student]` and `[Course]` as a composite key (means they are unique), see the 1 and 2, if they select the "Jack" as the lecturer, I want the `[Student]`, `[Course]` and `[Lecturer]` as a composite key.

So:

- They can only create one record for each `[Student]` and `[Course]`
- But they can create multiple records if they select "Jack" for `[Lecturer]`

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, Student + course must be unique if they are normal record, but if the lectuer is "Jack",  the "Student + course" won't be unique any more, what I thought is creating a same table and following the same data structure, but the second table remove the Key, 

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

In the above table you have given, you should add all 4 fields except ID as composite key to achieve the result.

Assuming combo of Sam,English,Andrew, English_1 is always unique.

Edit:
Another option is as below.

Keep student+course in a table called course registration. Add both fields as composite alternate key.

And have another table called lesson schedule

Which has foreign key of course registration & lecturer & lesson. So u can add these 3 coulmns as unique key if need be.

Comment: But If we put all 4 fields as composite key, how can we restrict the [Student] and [Course]? they can create multiple, but I only want: if they select "Jack" as Lecturer, then they can create multiple, otherwise they can only create one

Comment: Edited my response to answer this situation

Comment: How can we restrict that only  selected Jack then have multiple lessons, otherwise only one lesson

Comment: It has to be a plugin and cannot be a alternate key anymore as ur logic is conditional.

Comment: Alternate Keys will work only on non-null fields, means unique constraint will not get effect if one of the fields in the composite key is null. So if no Jack then unique key will not trigger. So next best option is plugin where you have control over how the unique key is triggered. Other options would be to create a text field which will hold the Guids of the references concatenated and make that field alternate key.